# How to deserialize json file with dynamic child?

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, xamarin.forms, json.net

I have JsonFile to get data from , and that file can be change at time like nested object, so I need a solution for every change in the file

```
{
"Result": [{
    "ProductIid": 883,
    "Mark": "KCD",
    "Position": null,
    "ChildProduct": [{
        "ProductIid": 8831,
        "Mark": "KCE",
        "Position": "AU20001",
    }]
},
{
  "ProductIid": 999,
    "Mark": "POM",
    "Position": null
},
```

And change can look this for example :

```
{
"Result": [{
    "ProductIid": 883,
    "Mark": "KCD",
    "Position": null,
    "ChildProduct": [{
        "ProductIid": 8831,
        "Mark": "KCE",
        "Position": "AU20001",
        "ChildProduct": [{
              "ProductIid": 8832,
              "Mark": "KCF",
              "Position": "20001",
            }]
    }]
},
{
  "ProductIid": 999,
    "Mark": "POM",
    "Position": null
},
```

Already I can get data from file like this, but its static solution:

```
var responseData = streamReader.ReadToEnd();  
rootObject=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject(responseData);

JObject testData = JObject.Parse(responseData);
JArray child = (JArray)testData["Result"][0]["Child"];
```

Comment: Is it truly dynamic or are they just a subsets of a wider specification?

Comment: Does JSON have completely different structure or it is some well-defined set of possible structures?

Comment: I think is not important is this case , however I need to show all data

Comment: It is very important and pertinent to an easy solution

Comment: Ok so I think they a subsets of a wider specification

Comment: Do you mean it maybe contains several "ChildProduct" in each "ChildProduct"?

Comment: Yes, thats can happen

Comment: I think you can try to use an iterative method to get the last "ChildProduct", and then retrieve the data you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the JSON you provided, this seems quite simple, e.g.

```
public class Product
{
    public long ProductIid {get;set;}
    public string Mark {get;set;}
    public string Position {get;set;}
    public Product[] ChildProduct {get;set;}
}

var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product[]>(responseData);
```